# Mysql - Which index is better?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have 2 column like this:

Column A | Column B

and these column are searchable. I want to search both of them at the same time. Should I index a pair of key (A,B) or index seperate A and B. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite index over `(A, B)` may be used for some queries involving *only* `A` and some queries involving *both* `A` and `B`, but *never* on queries involving only `B`.

Which index is better depends on the queries you will be performing over your data.

Not only that, the order of the fields in your index is also relevant, since an index over `(A, B)` and an index over `(B, A)` may be useful in different situations.

To complicate matters even more, some queries can use the index alone without accessing the data in the tables, e.g., if your query is `SELECT B FROM table WHERE A = 5` and you have an index over `(A, B)`, the engine may only traverse the index, since it contains all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally,* if you only ever search for a value containing *both* columns, a single composite index across both would be better. This means you'll get a set of rows containing only that combined value from the index itself. If you had a single or separate keys, you'd have to either strip out irrelevant rows after the initial load, or do two loads and work out their intersection.

If you think you may want to search for either column independently, I'd also have separate indexes on each.

However, this is based on generalities. You should be using the tools at your disposal (such as `explain` in MySQL) to evaluate the performance of your queries, *using data representative of what you'll see in the real environment.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search both fields at the same time, you need a combined index in both fields.

If an index is made in both fields A and B you can lookup the entries directly when using both fields in a query. Also you can use this index for queries involving only A.

If you have only separate indexes on each field, the database can use only one of them in a query. Then it would habe to scan all remaining entries to find the second field.

See here for reference: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: Can you tell me what is difference between INDEX name (A, B) with INDEX name (A) and INDEX name (B). 
Sorry i very bad English
Thanks!!

Comment: @ĐôngĐứcĐỗ - A partial answer is in my [_index cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#redundant_excessive_indexes).

Answer (score 0):

**case 1:**

```
WHERE A = x AND B = y
ORDER BY B
```

**key:** (A, B)

**case 2:**

```
WHERE A = x AND B = y
ORDER BY A
```

**key:** (B, A)

**case 3:**

```
WHERE A = x OR B = y (any order)
```

**keys:** (A), (B)